# Required fields in Mechanical Turk

Tags: mechanicalturk

Is there any way to make fields required in an Amazon Mechanical Turk HIT? I get some blank responses to the textboxes or radiobuttons in my HTML form and the Amazon's documentation doesn't seem to provide any mechanism for validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to use Amazon's API call 'createHIT' to create your HIT: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/index.html?ApiReference_CreateHITOperation.html

Then, you can specify your HIT questions using a 'questionForm' data structure, which allows defining any field as 'required', and enforces it when the form is submitted.

Comment: Thanks. I have used the API before and I think I'm limited when I used the questionsForm and my HTML form is more complex. I was hoping that there is some kind of validation mechanism when the users are submitting the HIT.

Comment: yep, I've actually bumped into your question while looking a solution for the same issue :)

Answer (score 2):

I think adding the **required** attribute to your element works fine.

```
<input class="form-control" id="url" name="url" placeholder="Enter URL here" required="" type="url" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you create your HIT on an external server, used javascript for form validation and then display the questionnaire on Mechanical Turk using an iFrame.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind creating an external web app to host your question form, you can create an external HIT and do your validation there.