# Submission Validation with the Crowd Template on MTurk

Tags: javascript, mechanicalturk

I have a mturk survey and would like to validate the results when clicking the submit button. I found out there is one way discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946829/javascript-validation-prevent-submit-form-amazon-mechanical-turk). However, that does not seem to work. Does anyone have any idea?

My code (JS part):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {document.getElementById('submitButton').setAttribute('onclick', 'return validateForm()'); }

function validateForm() {
    alert("test");
    return false;
}
```

There is no alert and the submission succeeded.

Comment: Solution: please see the answer below. Keep in mind that this should be put at the very last part of the layout HTML code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the new [Crowd HTML Elements](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_HTMLCustomElementsArticle.html), you can hook into the submit event and do your pre-validation like this:

```
document.querySelector('crowd-form').onsubmit = function(e ) {
    if (!validateForm()) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Thank you,

Amazon Mechanical Turk