# Required Questions in mTurk Crowd HTML Elements

Tags: html, mechanicalturk

I have an HTML that first calls `<script src="https://assets.crowd.aws/crowd-html-elements.js"></script>` then I use the `<crowd-form>` function and within that form there are a few `<crowd-radio-group>` elements. The HTML file looks something like this:

```
`<script src="https://assets.crowd.aws/crowd-html-elements.js"></script>
<crowd-form>
<crowd-radio-group>
    <crowd-radio-button name="1" value=1></crowd-radio-button>
    <crowd-radio-button name="2" value=2></crowd-radio-button>
</crowd-radio-group>
</crowd-form>`
```

However, the form can be easily submitted without any sort of requirement checking to make sure the user selected one of the radio buttons. Is there any way to do this using the Crowd HTML Elements?

I've looked at this post ([Submission Validation with the Crowd Template on MTurk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54266891/submission-validation-with-the-crowd-template-on-mturk/58088579?noredirect=1#comment102570476_58088579)) but don't know how to implement the answer into my HTML file.

Thanks